# Div with width:100% , bottom responsive div, being a child is not an option

Tags: css, html, height

Ok here's what I have:

```
<div id='wrap' style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
  <div id='parent'style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
  </div>
<div>
```

Now I want a `<div id='downleft'>` which would be `left: 0; bottom: 0;`.

The ideal would have been if I just included `id='downleft'` inside the `id='parent'` which is responsive, like:

```
<div id='wrap' >
   <div id='parent'>
      <div id='downleft'></div>
   </div>
<div>
```

**Unfortunately** `parent` is handled by a script and everything inside it is not generated in final website (there are some other divs generated inside it).

**Question:**

Is there any way that  `id='downleft'` can always have a responsive position based on `id='parent'`'s responsive height, on the bottom left of the page?

ps: Unfortunately jsfiddle doesn't support height:100% for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the content that is generated before downleft, so that the downleft would alwyas be the last element inside the parent.

eg `$("#downleft").before(javascript generated content)

`